# FusionCharts: How to have a stacked column chart along with area chart in a single chart

Tags: json, fusioncharts

I want to display a chart using fusion charts with stacked column chart along with area chart.

Is there an option to create the same? I went through the fusion charts website but did not find that option is combination charts.

Below is my code:

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var salesAnlysisChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'mscombi2D',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '600',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
        "categories": [{
            "category": [{
                "label": "25 Jun - \r\n01 Jul"
            },
            {
                "label": "02 Jul - \r\n08 Jul"
            },
            {
                "label": "09 Jul - \r\n15 Jul"
            },
            {
                "label": "16 Jul - \r\n22 Jul"
            }]
        }],
        "chart": {
            "showPlotBorder": "0",
            "showValues": "0",
            "showToolTip": "1",
            "caption": "Line1",
            "YAxisName": "Demand",
            "showBorder": "0",
            "canvasBorderThickness": "1",
            "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
            "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
            "showToolTipShadow": "1",
            "toolTipBgAlpha": "90",
            "bgColor": "#ffffff",
            "canvasBorderColor": "#f2f2f2",
            "xAxisName": "Timeline",
            "toolTipBorderColor": "#333333",
            "toolTipBgColor": "#ffffff",
            "legendBorderThickness": "0",
            "divLineColor": "#f2f2f2",
            "legendShadow": "0"
        },
        "dataset": [{
            "seriesname": "Five Days",
            "color": "#92d3e4",
            "data": [{
                "value": 4262
            },
            {
                "value": 4524
            },
            {
                "value": 4804
            },
            {
                "value": 4528
            }]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "Overtime (1 Day)",
            "color": "#2ea2c0",
            "data": [{
                "value": 1067
            },
            {
                "value": 619
            },
            {
                "value": 762
            },
            {
                "value": 1009
            }]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "Overtime (2 Days)",
            "color": "#366082",
            "data": [{
                "value": 887
            },
            {
                "value": 910
            },
            {
                "value": 1152
            },
            {
                "value": 1110
            }]
        },
        {
            "anchorHoverEffect": "1",
            "seriesname": "Demand",
            "showValues": "0",
            "anchorRadius": "3",
            "color": "#e9f057",
            "data": [{
                "value": 4.9E-323
            },
            {
                "value": 4230
            },
            {
                "value": 4230
            },
            {
                "value": 4230
            }],
            "anchorHoverRadius": "5",
            "parentYAxis": "S",
            "renderAs": "line",
            "anchorBgColor": "#e9f057"
        },
        {
        "seriesname": "Cum. Capacity",
        "color": "#2ea2c0",
        "renderAs": "area",
        "data": [{
            "value": 4262
        },
        {
            "value": 4566
        },
        {
            "value": 5140
        },
        {
            "value": 5438
        }]
        }],
        "trendlines": [{
            "line": [{
                "displayValue": "5 Day Capacity",
                "isTrendZone": "1",
                "color": "#da433f",
                "thickness": "2",
                "valueOnRight": "1",
                "startValue": 4468,
                "valuePadding": "10",
                "tooltext": "5 Day Capacity: 4468.0"
            }]
        }]
        }
    }).render();
});
```

The column charts are not stacked.
If i use type='stackedcolumn2dline' then the area chart become stacked too.
Is there a way to get this done?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

yes as of now you can have stackedcolumn2dline chart as the only combination chart which has stacked plot in it, however, you can raise a request FusionCharts support.

They could assist you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To render a stacked area chart in 2D, change the value of the type attribute from stackedcolumn3d to stackedarea2d

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedarea2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '600',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Harry's SuperMart",
        "subCaption": "Product-wise quarterly revenue in current year",
        "xAxisname": "Quarter",
        "yAxisName": "Amount",
        "numberPrefix": "$"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Q1"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q2"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q3"
          },
          {
            "label": "Q4"
          }
        ]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Food Products",
          "data": [{
              "value": "11000"
            },
            {
              "value": "15000"
            },
            {
              "value": "13500"
            },
            {
              "value": "15000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
          "data": [{
              "value": "11400"
            },
            {
              "value": "14800"
            },
            {
              "value": "8300"
            },
            {
              "value": "11800"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }).render();
});
```

To know more about this refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/stacked-charts#stacked-area-2d-chart

Here is a Demo Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/qjryvs6n/